# How to connect a promise to this chain?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a function that retrieve data of one user. Now I want to get in this function the user_id like that:

```
    this.storage.get(USER_ID).then(val => {
             this.id = val;
)}
```

so the api knows from which user it need the id.
My main function I have to insert this is:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.authService.authenticationStateSubject.pipe(
      switchMap(isAuthenticated => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
          return this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      }),
    ).subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result) {
          this.information = result;
          console.log(this.information);
        } else {
        }
      },
      error => {
      }
    );
  }
```

I tried to put my snippet right after the `if (isAuthenticated) {` but somehow it doesn't work with the two last brackets. Can I actually connect these two snippets?

combined version

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.authService.authenticationState,
    from(this.storage.get(USER_ID))
    .pipe(
      switchMap(([isAuthenticated, id]) => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
          return this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      }),
    ).subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result) {
          this.information = result;
          console.log(this.information);
        } else {
        }
      },
      error => {
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use from to convert your promise to an observable and use combineLatest with the authenticationStateSubject

```
this.subscription = combineLatest(
  this.authService.authenticationStateSubject, 
  from(this.storage.get(USER_ID))
).pipe(
  switchMap(
    ([isAuthenticated, id]) => isAuthenticated ? this.userService.getUserDetails(id) : of(null)
  )
).subscribe(
  result => {
    // do stuff with result
  }
);
```

Comment: I don't really get where to assign val to my id.

Comment: combineLatest emits an array of the input observables, id is already in the array. You don't need your unwrapping of the promise as it is done with from.

Comment: with from I get an error that it does not exist for type boolean behavior subject

Comment: You pass in the promise to from, not the behavior subject.

Comment: I have updated my question do you mean it like that? But now I have for id that its declared but never read, where do I get the value from ?